# Dynamic shape mailto hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a dynamic mailto hyperlink on a textbox. The email address is the text inside the textbox.

One idea I had is to make a vba macro to run when clicking the textbox that would get the caller text and run the command, but I don't know how to run the mailto command in a simple way. I'm using Lotus Notes instead of Outlook.

Comment: See my [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f9379b61-ffc6-491d-b36e-e9b37885ee7e/how-do-i-send-an-email-from-excel-containing-only-certain-cells-from-the-workbook#a67ce1c7-e269-40c2-8c50-bfba3cf15323) on how to send email via Lotus Notes.

Comment: I thought about doing a whole procedure to create the email, but the mailto hyperlink does  exactly what I need in a much cleaner way. I just don't know how to customize the address, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a answer for this question.

Using a Shell command it's possible to emulate the mailto command.

```
Shell ("cmd.exe /c start mailto:" & strMAilAddress)
```

With this is possible to use `Application.Caller` to get the text on the Text Box and make a dynamic hyperlink on a shape.